# How to change headers for specific types of files served in IIS / MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, http-headers

I am implementing a fix for the problem caused by 02 compression issues over 3G.

[Web site exhibits JavaScript error on iPad / iPhone under 3G but not under WiFi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282373/web-site-exhibits-javascript-error-on-ipad-iphone-under-3g-but-not-under-wifi)

The best solution seems to be http://stuartroebuck.blogspot.com/2010/08/official-way-to-bypassing-data.html which is basically to add the header `Cache-Control: no-transform` in IIS, however I would like to apply this only to specific file types. What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the best solution for me to write a HttpModule. I wrote an example for you.
You can check mime type for specific file types.

```
public class AddHeaderModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.EndRequest += OnEndRequest;
    }

    void OnEndRequest(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if(HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType == "image/jpeg")
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-transform");
    }
}
```

Also you have to add it web.config

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <httpModules>
         <add name="AddHeaderModule" type="your.namespace.AddHeaderModule" />
      </httpModules>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```