# Web source changes how source looks

Tags: javascript, css, external

All my css and js files are external files (linked in template).When looking at localhost source it looks very nice :

```
    <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
<title> Hellscream Fury</title>
<!-- TemplateEndEditable  -->
<link href="../css/usermain.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="../libs/froalaeditor/css/froala_page.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/froalaeditor/js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.wowhead.com/widgets/power.js"></script><script>var wowhead_tooltips = { "colorlinks": true, "iconizelinks": true, "renamelinks": true }</script>
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="head" -->
<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
</head>
```

However once uploaded site to a web server and checking how view source looks it shows all the external files, not just links to them like that :

```
  <!doctype html><html><script src="http://1.2.3.4/bmi-int-js/bmi.js" language="javascript"></script><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>Log in | Hellscream Fury</title> <style type="text/css" style="display:none">@charset"utf-8";html,body{margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;}#changepass{width:400px;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;text-align:right;}#sec_question{margin-top:5px;padding:2.5px;text-align:right;width:209px;!important height:60px;font-weight:bold;color:#CCC;}#seqquestion select{margin-top:5px;padding:2.5px;text-align:right;width:209px;!important height:60px;font-weight:bold;color:#CCC;}#seqquestion{width:350px;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;text-align:right;padding:10px;margin-bottom:50px;border-radius:15px;}.bborderblcok{border:2px solid #05EDFF;border-radius:15px;margin-bottom:50px;padding:10px;}#alts{width:100%;}html{-webkit-background-size:cover;-moz-background-size:cover;-o-background-size:cover;background-size:cover;background-attachment:fixed;background-image:url(http://hellscreamsfury.com/css/../assets/bg.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center center;}#container{position:relative;width:600px;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;margin-top:90px;margin-bottom:70px;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.85);color:#CCC;}.redWarning{color:#aa0114;}.content{min-height:100px;height:100px;height:auto!important;height:100px;padding-top:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-left:10px;padding-bottom:70px;}label{font-size:18px;}header{border-bottom-width:1px;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-color:#AA0114;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{color:#01b2f1;text-align:center;}h1{font-size:36px;}footer{position:absolute;bottom:0px;width:100%;height:70px;left:0px;border-top-width:1px;border-top-style:solid;border-top-color:#AA0114;text-align:center;}.serverLogo{position:absolute;top:-90px;}#LoginForm label{color:#CCC;font-weight:bold;font-size:18px;font-family:"Palatino Linotype","Book Antiqua",Palatino,serif;padding-right:25px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:10px;}input{margin-top:5px;padding:2.5px;text-align:center;background-color:#333;border:2px solid #333;color:#CCC;width:200px;height:40px;font-weight:bold;}input:focus{background-color:#333;border:2px solid #05EDFF;color:#CCC;}#username:focus,#password:focus{background-color:#333;border:2px solid #05EDFF;color:#CCC;}.button{width:100px;height:50px;margin-top:30px;display:inline-block;font-weight:normal;font-size:medium;cursor:pointer;}#login{width:300px;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;text-align:right;}.centre{text-align:center;}a{color:#05EDFF;text-decoration:none;}a:hover{text-decoration:underline;}#register{width:500px;padding-right:10px;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;text-align:right;background-image:url(http://hellscreamsfury.com/css/../assets/flag_horde.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;margin-bottom:25px;}.announcments{text-align:center;}.announcments h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{text-align:center;}.announcments h1{font-size:50px;}.selectbox{width:161px;float:left;margin-right:5px;margin-bottom:10px;}p{font-size:18px;}h3{font-size:24px;}em{display:block;margin-top:5px;}select{margin-top:5px;padding:2.5px;background-color:#333;border:2px solid #333;color:#CCC;width:160px;height:40px;}select:focus{background-color:#333;border:2px solid #05EDFF;}.green{color:#8fde62;text-align:center;}#sprytextfield4 .textfieldRequiredMsg{width:auto;}#recovery{text-align:right;width:300px;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;margin-bottom:50px;}
</style>
<style type="text/css" style="display:none">@charset"UTF-8";/**//**//**/.textfieldRequiredMsg,.textfieldInvalidFormatMsg,.textfieldMinValueMsg,.textfieldMaxValueMsg,.textfieldMinCharsMsg,.textfieldMaxCharsMsg,.textfieldValidMsg{display:none;}/**/.textfieldRequiredState .textfieldRequiredMsg,.textfieldInvalidFormatState .textfieldInvalidFormatMsg,.textfieldMinValueState .textfieldMinValueMsg,.textfieldMaxValueState .textfieldMaxValueMsg,.textfieldMinCharsState .textfieldMinCharsMsg,.textfieldMaxCharsState .textfieldMaxCharsMsg{display:inline-block;color:#CCCCCC;clear:both;margin-top:3px;margin-bottom:3px;padding:5px;width:250px;text-align:center;background-color:#CC3333;opacity:0.8;}/**//**/.textfieldValidState input,input.textfieldValidState{background-color:#B8F5B1;color:#333;font-weight:bold;}/**/input.textfieldRequiredState,.textfieldRequiredState input,input.textfieldInvalidFormatState,.textfieldInvalidFormatState input,input.textfieldMinValueState,.textfieldMinValueState input,input.textfieldMaxValueState,.textfieldMaxValueState input,input.textfieldMinCharsState,.textfieldMinCharsState input,input.textfieldMaxCharsState,.textfieldMaxCharsState input{background-color:#FF9F9F;color:#CCC;}/**/.textfieldFocusState input,input.textfieldFocusState{background-color:#FFFFCC;color:#333;}/**/.textfieldFlashText input,input.textfieldFlashText{color:red!important;}/**/.textfieldHintState input,input.textfieldHintState{/**/}#step2form{width:250px;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;}
</style>
<style type="text/css" style="display:none">@charset"UTF-8";/**//**//**/.passwordRequiredMsg,.passwordInvalidStrengthMsg,.passwordMinCharsMsg,.passwordMaxCharsMsg,.passwordCustomMsg,.passwordValidMsg{display:none;}/**/.passwordRequiredState .passwordRequiredMsg,.passwordMinCharsState .passwordMinCharsMsg,.passwordMaxCharsState .passwordMaxCharsMsg,.passwordInvalidStrengthState .passwordInvalidStrengthMsg,.passwordCustomState .passwordCustomMsg{display:inline-block;color:#CCCCCC;clear:both;margin-top:3px;margin-bottom:3px;padding:5px;width:250px;text-align:center;background-color:#CC3333;opacity:0.8;}/**//**/.passwordValidState input,input.passwordValidState{background-color:#B8F5B1;display:inline-block;clear:both;}/**/input.passwordRequiredState,.passwordRequiredState input,input.passwordInvalidStrengthState,.passwordInvalidStrengthState input,input.passwordMinCharsState,.passwordMinCharsState input,input.passwordCustomState,.passwordCustomState input,input.passwordMaxCharsState,.passwordMaxCharsState input{background-color:#FF9F9F;}/**/.passwordFocusState input,input.passwordFocusState{background-color:#FFFFCC;}
</style>
```

This is just small part of everything shown.
My question is how to make them appear just as links when uploaded to web server?

Comment: When you’re viewing your HTML on the web server, are you doing so over an internet connection provided by a mobile phone company?

Comment: Yes. Actually using mobile tethering while dont have proper connection..is that the problem?Checked other websites through the same connection and source looks nice with external links.

Comment: It depends on your definition of “problem”, but yup, many mobile phone networks cache and transform HTML and other assets on the web so that they can be delivered using less bandwidth. If you can control the HTTP headers on your server, you can stop it: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113268/how-to-stop-javascript-injection-from-vodafone-proxy and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282373/web-site-exhibits-javascript-error-on-ipad-iphone-under-3g-but-not-under-wifi/

Comment: You’re very most welcome, this is pretty inexplicable when you first see it.